# Error: "-su: attr: command not found"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, attr, yowsup

Getting following error:

```
fhem@raspberrypi:/opt/yowsup-master$ attr WhatsApp cmd /opt/yowsup-master/yowsup-cli demos -c /opt/yowsup-config/yowsup.config --yowsup
-su: attr: command not found
```

Thy for all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install attr.

```
apt-get install attr
```

Comment: Thx a lot that one worked I tried installing it with the .tar.gz and with pip install attr but yours worked!